# How to process all rows of a DataGridView instead of just the first row

Tags: vb.net

The below code only affects the first row of the DataGridView but I want to affect all rows. Can anyone help me do that?

```
Private arLetterChars() As Char = "ÇÈÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÝÞßáãäåæí"
Private arEncryptedChars() As Char = "أبتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكتمنهوي"

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    With GV_Products.Rows(0).Cells(7).ToString

        For Each myTextBoxChar As Char In GV_Products.Rows(0).Cells(7).Value.ToString 
            For i As Integer = 0 To arLetterChars.Length - 1 
                If myTextBoxChar = arLetterChars(i) Then GV_Products.Rows(0).Cells(7).Value = GV_Products.Rows(0).Cells(7).Value.Replace(myTextBoxChar, arEncryptedChars(i))
            Next
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

I changed the code as below

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In GV_Products.Rows
    For Each myTextBoxChar As Char In row.Cells(5).Value.ToString
        For i As Integer = 0 To arLetterChars.Length - 1
           If myTextBoxChar = arLetterChars(i) Then row.Cells(5).Value = row.Cells(5).Value.Replace(myTextBoxChar, arEncryptedChars(i))
        Next
    Next
 Next
```

but still this error occured System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: The reason it only works for the 1st row is because you're specifying an index of 0 for the rows. An iterator variable from a `For` loop could be used in place of 0 or you could just use a `For Each` loop. After all, you're using both of them to do other looping in this code.

Comment: Thank for you, but I tried to do this I couldn't . could you adjust my code & put it here?. thanks

Comment: Your first problem is the `With` statement. It's not needed. Replace that with `For Each row As DataGridViewRow In GV_Products.Rows` then Change all the `GV_Products.Rows(0)` to just `row` The `End With` becomes `Next` then see how that goes.

Comment: Once you get this working, go to the very top of your code and put `Option Strict On` this will show you problems that you really should fix.

Comment: I changed the code as below ` For Each row As DataGridViewRow In GV_Products.Rows

            For Each myTextBoxChar As Char In row.Cells(5).Value.ToString
                               For i As Integer = 0 To arLetterChars.Length - 1
                    If myTextBoxChar = arLetterChars(i) Then row.Cells(5).Value = row.Cells(5).Value.Replace(myTextBoxChar, arEncryptedChars(i))
                Next
            Next

        Next`    but still this error was occured System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Can you please edit your post and put that comment into a code window for readability. Once done, then you can delete your last comment and I will help you fix this last issue.

Comment: I tried but I couldn't to comment as code . sorry for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're showing usually comes from having the "Allow users to add rows" set to True. This is the extra row at the bottom of the datagridview that lets the user continue adding rows.

You can set that to false if it's not needed but I prefer to check for it in code in case you later need to turn it on and forget to check for it.

You should just need to change your code to

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In GV_Products.Rows
    If Not row.IsNewRow Then 'Only run the inner code if we're not on the edit row.
        For Each myTextBoxChar As Char In row.Cells(5).Value.ToString
            For i As Integer = 0 To arLetterChars.Length - 1
                If myTextBoxChar = arLetterChars(i) Then row.Cells(5).Value = row.Cells(5).Value.Replace(myTextBoxChar, arEncryptedChars(i))
            Next
        Next
    End If
 Next
```

Comment: Glad to help. You should mark this as the answer since it helped your issue.